# Multiple SPA's with node.js and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, single-page-application

Is it meaningful to have multiple AngularJS SPA and single node.js app for large enterprise projects?

I.e. home, login and users are express routes and children/partials would be routed in AngularJS as SPA. With that I would break static content (js, css..) to smaller packages/files, get control over public content (authentication for backend content), more evenly server load etc.

- /home

  - /about
  - /contact
  - /products
- /login

  - /login
  - /register
  - /password-reset
- /users

  - /list all
  - /details
  - /create
    .
    .
    .